# conditional property setting

Tags: ant

How can i set a single property to different values based on conditions. My scenario is as follows:
1) Loop through different values of messageid
2) Give different 'comment' for each messageid

```
   <for list="12,23,34,45" param="messageid">
   <sequential>
      <condition property="comment" value="wireMsg-Inbound">
         <equals arg1="messageid" arg2="12"/>
      </condition>
      <condition property="comment" value="wireMsg-Outbound">
         <equals arg1="messageid" arg2="12"/>
      </condition>     
      <condition property="comment" value="appMsg-Inbound">
         <equals arg1="messageid" arg2="12"/>
      </condition>
      <condition property="comment" value="appMsg-Outbound">
         <equals arg1="messageid" arg2="12"/>
      </condition>
       </sequential>
   </for>
```

Is this valid? Is there any other way?
Also if i want to go through the loop each time the property comment should get updated with the new value, but since properties are immutable, how do i solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually want to loop over each value in the list, set the comment property, and then do something with it?  Or do you just want to set the comment property once, based on what is in the list? Are the values in the list constant?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Where is that list value coming from? Are you trying to set a single "comment" based on the value of some other property? Or do you have a comma-delineated list, and need to set separate properties for each value in that list? The example you gave is entirely static and will never change in behavior (e.g. it doesn't rely on any properties), so it's not clear what the inputs/outputs to it are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

The [variable task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) is mutable.  It's in the ant contrib library which I see you are already using for the for task.